# Parsing data in uitableview application

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, uitableview, cell

I am parsing data from multiple xml files in my iOS application and I need to put all the data together in 1 table. However, whenever I try to change the number of rows in the section to a number such as 5, instead of what is currently there I get an error. I also would like to add two cell identifiers but I am also getting issues when adding an extra cell identifier in the cellforRowatIndexPath method.

```
  - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSLog(@"retrieving");
        xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://nodeon"];
 xmlParser1 = [[XMLParser1 alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://nodeonon"];

       }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
        - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *) tableView
        {
            return 1;
        }

        - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {

            return [[xmlParser nodes] count];

        }

        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
            VMdelivered *nodes = [[xmlParser nodes] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
            UILabel *label;
            label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            label.text = [nodes nodeid];
            label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
            label.text = [nodes lastoutput];
            return cell;

        }


        - (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            return 55;
        }
```

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: I am getting a signal SIGABRT error every time I change it

Comment: The value you are returning must be <= [[xmlParser nodes] count];`. *http://www.vmhost04-vm1.bdva/nodeRepresentation* is an invalid URL, so I'm expecting `[[xmlParser nodes] count]` returns 0.

Comment: I put a false url because the actual url is confidential information, but it is valid

Comment: I understand. What about the **x** *less than or equal to* `[[xmlParser nodes] count]` comment?

Comment: Why do you want to hard code a number in numberOfRowsInSection instead of what you have now?

Comment: @rdelmar I have to parse from multiple xml files, so I need more rows than just [[xmlParser nodes] number of nodes. I have 3 xml files to parse from so I have 3 XMLParser classes and I need a seperate row in the table for each class.